# Extract ASL log entries written by ask_log

Tags: ios, logging

I'm using CocoaLumberjack with DDASLLogger to get log entries to the ASL, and
I want to have a single log with both misc NSLog:ed output from 3:rd party and my own
logs as well in the same log.

To get a better picture, I extracted the calls to ASL and made an example.
The problem I'm having is that this ASL extraction method only finds entries
that were **written with NSLog**, not the one with **asl_log**.

Here is an example from the Organizer Console:

```
Apr 17 20:34:48 Claes-Ls-iPhone-4s ASLLogTest[7253] <Warning>: NSLog 7
Apr 17 20:34:51 Claes-Ls-iPhone-4s ASLLogTest[7253] <Critical>: ASLLog 7
```

When extracting this, I'm only getting the NSLog line.

Here is the code used:

**Writing to ASL:**

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary;
NSString *productName = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
_client = asl_open(productName.UTF8String, "com.apple.console", 0);
int status = asl_log(_client, NULL, ASL_LEVEL_CRIT, "%s", string.UTF8String);
```

**Reading from ASL (not providing the complete iterate-through-asl, but it works):**

```
// Using ASL_QUERY_OP_TRUE to be dead-sure.
q = asl_new(ASL_TYPE_QUERY);
asl_set_query(q, ASL_KEY_SENDER, productName.UTF8String, ASL_QUERY_OP_TRUE);
aslresponse r = asl_search(NULL, q);
```

What am I missing, is it impossible to write to ASL and then read it this way?

Thanks,
Claes

Comment: looking for the same solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift, there's a new open-source project called [CleanroomASL](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomASL) that provides a type-safe API for reading and writing Apple System Log entries.

Querying the log for a given `.Sender` (assume `productName` is a `String` or `NSString`):

```
let client = ASLClient()
let query = ASLQueryObject()
query.setQueryKey(.Sender, value: productName, operation: .EqualTo, modifiers: .None)

client.search(query) { record in
    if let record = record {
        // we've gotten a log entry for the search.
        // 'record' is of type ASLQueryObject.ResultRecord
    }
    else {
        // there are no more log entries to process
    }
    // return true while we still want to get results
    // or return false when we don't want to process more
    return true
}
```

**Note:** On an iOS device, ASL will *only* return log entries made by your process. Also, logs are pruned rather aggressively, and may only include entries made by the current run of your application. Further differences between ASL behavior on the Mac/iOS Simulator and on an iOS device are [explained here](https://github.com/emaloney/CleanroomASL/#differences-between-the-device-and-simulator).